# what is the difference between apply and no-apply and partial in clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

In this code,

```
user> (= (apply partial partial [+])
     (partial partial +))
false
user>
```

what is the difference between

> (apply partial partial [+])

and

> (partial partial +)

?

In this code,

```
user> (= (apply +  [])
     (+))
true
```

why the return value is not false then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general definition of function equality in `Clojure`. There is the trivial identity, if two objects are the same they apply as equal. But partial creates a new object. For example:

```
user> (= (partial + 0) (partial + 0))
false
```

As human readers we can see that these are the same function (and both are the same function as `+` itself). But there is no logic in the Clojure language that allows that sort of equality to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
(apply +  [])
;0

(+)
;0
```

... then

```
(= (apply + []) (+))
;true
```

---

... and, further to [@noisesmith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26085860/1562315),

```
(= (partial +) +)
;true
```

... because `partial` with one argument returns it.

```
(partial +)
;#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@5746e7cc>

+
;#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@5746e7cc>
```

But `partial` with several arguments *constructs* an anonymous function object. And functions are equal only if they are identical - the same object. Two such calls to `partial` - even with identical arguments - produce two *different* hence unequal objects.

```
(partial partial +)
;#<core$partial$fn__4198 clojure.core$partial$fn__4198@23f4ebfe>

(partial partial +)
;#<core$partial$fn__4198 clojure.core$partial$fn__4198@7d41b16b>
```